# SSRS Report Builder Loading Assembly Error

Tags: reporting-services, .net-assembly

I am simply trying to add an assembly reference to Report Builder. However, I copied the assembly's dll and added to (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin). After that i added the reference to it from the report builder.

However, upon trying to preview the report i get:

> An error occurred during local report processing. The definition of the report '' is invalid. Error while loading code module: 'PebbleReports.SsrsUtils, Version:1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, Details: Could not load file or assembly 'PebbleReports.SsrsUtils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any help is much appreciated, as I found nothing so far on google.

Answer (score 2):

try copying the DLLs to the following location:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies